# How to configure upload of webform document files to public folders?

Tags: webforms

When configuring the storage location of a webform document file,i am not proposed to changed it from private to public.

That is problématic to expose that URI to a distant server.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On /admin/structure/webform/config/elements, select *Allow files to be uploaded to public file system*.

Enabling it isn't recommended, though. See [Drupal file upload by anonymous or untrusted users into public file systems -- PSA-2016-003](https://www.drupal.org/psa-2016-003).